# Scratch quiz game randomizer not working

Tags: mit-scratch

I have an inventory of 30 variables that are randomly selected. When one variable is chosen a question that corresponds with that variable should appear. Instead no matter which variable is chosen, the block at the end of the code is chosen. I even got rid of the randomizer so I could choose which variable was chosen, but the code still went all the way to the bottom. How can I fix this?

Here is a screenshot of part of the code:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that none of your `if` blocks can ever evaluate to `false`. After all, `Inventory` *does* contain every of it's items. Therefore *every* `say` is executed, but everey output is replaced by the subsequent one. Due to the speed with which this happens, you can only see the last one.

A solution is to select an item into another variable and compare this variable to the list, like so:

[image]